# How to prevent the page from refreshing using laravel with alpinejs

Tags: php, laravel, alpine.js

I am having a problem on keeping the multi select dropdown visible after form validation. The process of this code is that a user will select a radio button and then a dropdown will appear. What I want to do is to keep the dropdown visible if the user submitted the form without selecting any values in the dropdown to test the validation but it keeps resetting because the page is refreshing every submission.

## request-document.blade.php

```
<div x-data="{ selectedOption: '' }" x-cloak>

    @include('e-request.request-radio-buttons')

    @include('e-request.request-multi-dropdown')

</div>
```

## request-radio-buttons.blade.php

```
<div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="request-radioButton" id="machinery-radioButton"
            value="Machinery" x-model="selectedOption">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="request-radioButton">
            Machinery
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="request-radioButton" id="request-radioButton"
            value="Facility" x-model="selectedOption">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="request-radioButton">
            Facility
        </label>
    </div>
    <div class="form-check form-check-inline">
        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="request-radioButton" id="request-radioButton"
            value="Tools" x-model="selectedOption">
        <label class="form-check-label" for="request-radioButton">
            Tools
        </label>
    </div>
```

## request-multi-dropdown.blade.php

```
<div x-show="selectedOption === 'Machinery'" x-init="initSelect2('multiDropdownMachinery')">
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="machineryType" class="form-label label-style">Machinery Type</label>
            <select id="multiDropdownMachinery" name="machineryType[]"
                class="form-select multiDropdownMachinery" multiple>
                <option value="4 Wheel Drive Tractor">4 Wheel Drive Tractor</option>
                <option value="Rice Combine Harvester">Rice Combine Harvester</option>
                <option value="Hand Tractor with Accessories">Hand Tractor with Accessories</option>
                <option value="Hauling Truck">Hauling Truck</option>
                <option value="Precision Seeder">Precision Seeder</option>
                <option value="Pump and Engine Set">Pump and Engine Set</option>
                <option value="Recirculating Dryer">Recirculating Dryer</option>
                <option value="Riding-Type Transplanter">Riding-Type Transplanter</option>
                <option value="Seed Cleaner">Seed Cleaner</option>
                <option value="Compact Ricemill">Compact Ricemill</option>
                <option value="Walk-Behind Transplanter">Walk-Behind Transplanter</option>
                <option value="Rice Thresher">Rice Thresher</option>
                <option value="Seed Spreader">Seed Spreader</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        @error('machineryType')
            <span class="fs-6 text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>

<div x-show="selectedOption === 'Facility'" x-init="initSelect2('multiDropdownFacility')">
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="facilityType" class="form-label label-style">Facility Type</label>
            <select id="multiDropdownFacility" name="facilityType[]" class="form-select multiDropdownFacility" multiple>
                <option value="Inspire">Inspire</option>
                <option value="RPC">RPC</option>
                <option value="Warehouse">Warehouse</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        @error('facilityType')
            <span class="fs-6 text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>

<div x-show="selectedOption === 'Tools'" x-init="initSelect2('multiDropdownTools')">
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <label for="toolType" class="form-label label-style">Tool Type</label>
            <select id="multiDropdownTools" name="toolType[]" class="form-select multiDropdownTools" multiple>
                <option value="Shovel">Shovel</option>
                <option value="Rake">Rake</option>
                <option value="Sickle">Sickle</option>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div>
        @error('toolType')
            <span class="fs-6 text-danger">{{ $message }}</span>
        @enderror
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried submitting the form without selecting any values in the dropdown and the error message appears only if I selected either of the radio buttons.

Comment: well how are you submitting the form?

Comment: I'm submitting it through controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"but it keeps resetting because the page is refreshing every submission." - no it keeps resetting because the selected value before the submission is lost. Try initiating the selected value via the `old()` function. Docs: https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/requests#retrieving-old-input

```php
<div x-data="{ selectedOption: `{{ old('request-radioButton') }}` }" x-cloak>

    @include('e-request.request-radio-buttons')

    @include('e-request.request-multi-dropdown')

</div>
```

Comment: My problem has been resolved now. I appreciate your help.